# gem -v command not found - CentOS 6.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install Ruby on CentOS 6.3 I've installed the ruby-1.9.3-p286 from source. However once completed, I tried doing gem -v to verify that gems was installed and I get  /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory. I thought this version of ruby would have automatically installed gems. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you supplied a `--prefix` directory before building it, Ruby (at least that version - couldn't say for sure about other versions) will install things in `/usr/local`. That would mean `gem` lives at `/usr/local/bin/gem`.

If that file is there, you might want to consider adding `/usr/local/bin` to your path:

```
# ~/.bashrc (or equivalent):
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```